# Visual Studio stops in the middle of publishing app service to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019, publish

I've got an app service that I can't get published to Azure as Visual Studio (2019 v16.11.20) keeps stopping in the middle of the process.

The build itself completes successfully.  When it gets to "Publish started" for some of my lower-level projects, it just stops.  No errors, no messages, no nothing.  Just done.  The UI is still active, so it's not completely hung, but the publish process won't continue.

- I've tried deleting .vs, no change.
- Deleting and re-importing the publish profile, no change.
- Deleting the build configuration, no change.
- Closing and re-starting VS, no change.
- Rebooting the machine, no change.
- Cleaning, rebuilding the solution, no change.
- Deleting the obj and bin directories throughout the solution, no change.

Publishing other solutions on the machine works properly.
Publishing other configurations of this solution works properly (to other subscriptions).
I think that I even tried deleting the app service and re-building it (we're pre-production, but getting to where we need to be ready to go), no change.
I found a reference to more verbose logging, but all that it shows is that it completes one of the steps and then nothing.  I don't have the logs any more, but could probably regenerate them if someone thinks it would help.

Every once and a while, it works, but I have no idea what the magic is to get it working every time.  Anyone have any ideas on what it would take to get this running properly?  I need to be able to start publishing this consistently as we start our final testing before release.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can you provide logs here?

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio stops in the middle of publishing app service to Azure:

***Need to check & resolve:***

- First of all, whenever you are publishing to Azure check whether any web app deployment existed in the selected profile or better create a new app service by clicking on "+".

[image]

- The simplest method to fix this kind of errors is to republish your code with the ["*Remove additional files at destination*"](https://build5nines.com/fix-net-core-http-error-500-30-after-publish-to-app-service-from-visual-studio/) option enabled detailed by @Chris Pietschmann.
- Change the target framework version since the target framework must match both the `.csproj` and the `pubxml` file locations. Otherwise, the publishing profile fails to locate its targets in the `assets.json` file.

If you'd like to change it, look in the `pubxml` file.

```xml
<TargetFramework> netcoreapp<version> </TargetFramework>
```

- > In the output window you can check at which stage does the publish website operation fail. Verify below:

[Publish failed](https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/595252-publish-failed)

- Check the Visual Studio version and upgrade to the most recent one (VS2022) because some of the previous versions contained issues. This type of problem could be caused by the `.NET` compilers package. So, they used to remove the `Microsoft.NET.compilers` package from `Nuget` and then publish.

*After checking these, I tried creating a .NET core WebApp and published to Azure that worked for me successfully.*

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems pubishing to Azure for years now, the publish always hangs visual studio I always ended up starting the solution in VS 2017, and publish from there. Now I found a solution. When I start VS 2022, i start it as a administrator in windows, and then publishing works all the time.